# Are MySQL processes supposed to "die", or stay alive?

Tags: linux, mysql

All other processes have "time" lengths less than 5 minutes, yet MySQL stayed alive since its last restart (4 days ago). The behavior I'm observing is: MySQL process never dies and increasingly spikes CPU/RAM even when no queries are happening. I can't imagine the spiking is normal behavior, but perhaps keeping the process alive to listen for requests is?

top

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND 
3210 mysql     15   0 1690m 305m 9340 S  0.3 14.9  99:08.97 mysql
```

ps aux

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
mysql     3210  1.7 14.9 1731008 313312 ?      Sl   May08  99:08 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql
```

MySQLTuner shows green "OK" in all boxes except Total Fragmented Tables: 122.
I'm using CentOS 6.6, Apache 2.2.29, and MySQL 5.6.

Comment: "All other processes have "time" lengths less than 5 minutes," Not all of them. See pid #1. :)

Comment: @EEAA At that rate, SSH stays alive too... so there's my question lol. Specifically, is it normal for MySQL process to stay alive? It's eating my RAM when I wait too long without restarting it (perhaps separate issue), and I've been trying to debug it in my spare time for months.

Comment: You *want* it to use RAM. It's doing what it is supposed to do, and is gradually building its in-memory cache of your database. By restarting it, you are decreasing performance significantly. If you can't spare the memory it needs, then I'd recommend adding RAM to the server.

Comment: @EEAA Thanks, I think this actually makes sense now. By adjusting MySQL to consume system resources for better performance (e.g. tweaking my.cnf based on MySQLTuner's recommendations), MySQL is working in such a way that it keeps cached information in RAM before using the disk... And that's why the RAM usage continually grows to a maximum. It also likely explains the CPU spikes, because retrieving/processing information from RAM is CPU intensive. Thanks man, I appreciate you clarifying that for me!